# Laravel Route Model Binding conflict when using the same structure with different models

Tags: php, laravel, route-model-binding

I'm trying to create a route model binding for two models: "User" and "Article"

`Route::get('/{user}', 'UsersController@show');`

`Route::get('/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');`

Problem is, one of these will always take precedence over the other, depending on the order they are declared.

I want the user route to take precedence over the articles route if a user and an article happends to have the same route, but the problem is that laravel returns a 404 page when it does not match a user, even if the route should match an article.

I know that you can use the where() function with regex for this, however both of these models uses the same structure for the route key name (they are both strings). Can I make the regex search a database column or something?

Comment: I would not be a bad idea to choose routes like `/users/{user}` and `/articles/{article}`. It not only prevents this from happening but might also help users to give a sense of where they currently are. Plus debugging.

Comment: I agree this is the best. Unfortunately my client wants it this way :)

Comment: Explain to him the technical issues related with applying that method . I totaly agree with what @ThomasVanderVeen said. But if you want to continue with that. you can solve the problem in the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 Options:

1. Use different routes for each:

```php
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@show');

Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
```

2. Customizing The Resolution Logic on your `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('userOrArticle', function ($value) {
        return is_numeric($value)
                    ? App\User::where('id', $value)->firstOrFail()
                    : App\Article::where('title', $value)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

```php
Route::get('/{userOrArticle}', function ($userOrArticle) {
    return $userOrArticle instanceof \App\User
                ? redirect()->action('UsersController@show', ['user' => $userOrArticle]);
                : redirect()->action('ArticlesController@show', ['article' => $userOrArticle]);
});
```

See 'Customizing The Resolution Logic' section of the docs for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: they are using strings for both

Comment: I believe this is what I want, but how do I use different controllers depending on the model? If it's a user it should go to UsersController@show and article should go to ArticlesController@show.

Comment: @gjerm94 I've updated my answer based on your needs.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Action App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@show not defined." Not sure what's wrong

Comment: @gjerm94 have you defined `UsersController` and `show` function on it? however, I prefer to use single name `UserController` I answered based on your question info.

Comment: @HafezDivandari I have a UsersController with a show method. I tried to define the routes beforehand aswell, however that brings back the original problem, where I get 404 errors. I tried with other controllers/methods and they don't work either so it's not a typo

Comment: @gjerm94 does your controller's method accept route parameter? is it named `user` or `article` as defined on the array? try to change to `['id' => $userOrArticle]` or whatever your method's parameter name are.

Comment: @HafezDivandari Yes, everything seems to be right. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Oh well, for now I'll use the other method you posted with UserOrArticleController, where I then new up the appropriate controllers and call the show() method. This is probably not best practice but it seems to work.